# Open Combobox in Excel Window

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a combo-box which works correctly, but it always seems to open on one monitor regardless of where I have excel open. I would like it to open "on top" of the excel application. Ideally it would be center screen on-top of the workbook as users can't "continue" until hitting the command_button.

I call the ComboBox via `ComboBox1.Show`, is there a way to place it in this part of the code?

I have tried all the options under `StartupPosition` but they all have undesireable effects.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which fixed it for me. Add the following to the `UserForm_Initialize` event.

```
Me.Top = Application.Top + (Application.UsableHeight / 2) - (Me.Height / 2)
Me.Left = Application.Left + (Application.UsableWidth / 2) - (Me.Width / 2)
```

Source:

https://bettersolutions.com/vba/userforms/positioning.htm